# How I can get the value of local variable 'head' in following code?

Tags: jquery

```
function call(){

  var th;
  var head;
  $('#coToolTable').on('click', '.edit',function () {
    th = $('#coToolTable th').eq($(this).index());

    head=th.text();
    alert("head="+head);

  });

  var values1 = $('table tr td :checkbox:checked').map(function () {
    return $(this).closest('tr').find('td:first').text()

  }).get();

  alert("values="+values1+"head="+head);
  check(values1,head);
}
```

In this function, when I run it then the `alert("head="+head);` gives output of my table header but in next alert box `alert("values="+values1+"head="+head);` it gives `head=undefined`. Why?

Comment: You need to use `.get(0)`.

Comment: Both of those alerts are correct. You need to research what javascript callbacks are.

Comment: How is the first `alert` even *happening* before the second `alert`?  The second one should take place when this function is called, but the first shouldn't take place until after something is clicked after this function is called.  This code is confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're assigning a value to `head` when you click on `#coToolTable`, not before that. Your second alert runs as soon as you execute `call()`, which is going to be before your click event handler runs and assigns a value to `head`. Therefore, when that second alert runs, you are seeing the value of `head` at the time it was declared: `undefined`.